# Using onOk prop of Modal.method() in Vue Ant Design

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use [Vue Ant's confirmation modal dialog](https://vue.ant.design/components/modal/#Confirmation-modal-dialog) but nothing seems to be accessible within the `onOk` prop. I try to call any of my methods or `this.$emit` but get `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined"`. I'd like to know how I can access my methods and data inside the `onOk` prop for this component.

```js
deleteCampaign() {
      this.$confirm({
        title: `Are you sure you want to delete ${this.campaign.name}?`,
        content: 'This will permanently delete the campaign and all associated info.',
        okText: 'Yes',
        okType: 'danger',
        cancelText: 'No',
        iconType: 'warning',
        onOk() {
          this.$emit('delete-campaign', this.campaign.pk);
        },
        onCancel() {},
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onOk() { ... }` should be an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) to bind the context to the Vue instance:

```
onOk: () => { this.$emit(...) }
```